# How to convert a nested dictionary with a list inside to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert this data into a dataframe..

`data = {123:  {'Feb': ['A', 'B'], 'Mar': ['A', 'B']}, 124: {'Feb': ['C'], 'Mar': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 125: {'Feb': ['A', 'C'], 'Mar': ['A']} }`

Wanted output:

| Acc Num | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 123 | 0 | B | 0 |
| 123 | 0 | 0 | A |
| 123 | 0 | 0 | B |
| 124 | 0 | C | 0 |
| 124 | 0 | 0 | A |
| 124 | 0 | 0 | B |
| 124 | 0 | 0 | C |
| 125 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 125 | 0 | C | 0 |
| 125 | 0 | 0 | A |

I have tried to use .explode() and did not get the proper results needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
out = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, orient='index').T
                for k, v in data.items()}, names=['Acc Num'])
          .reindex(months, axis=1).fillna(0).droplevel(1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Acc Num  Jan Feb Mar
0      123  0.0   A   A
1      123  0.0   B   B
2      124  0.0   C   A
3      124  0.0   0   B
4      124  0.0   0   C
5      125  0.0   A   A
6      125  0.0   C   0
```